# Having trouble converting string to int

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, treeview

In my program I have a `treeView`. In the section that I am working with, the node's `displayNames` are numerical `integer` values, but are displayed as `strings`. I have come to a point in my program where I need to convert and temporarily store these `displayNames` in an `integer` variable. I usually use `Regex.Match()` to do this with no problem, but in this scenario I am getting the compiler error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`.

This is my code:

```
//This is the parent node as you may be able to see below
//The children of this node have DisplayNames that are integers
var node = Data.GetAllChildren(x => x.Children).Distinct().ToList().First(x => x.identify == 'B');

//Get # of children -- if children exist
if (node.Children.Count() > 0)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count(); i++)
     {
          //Error on this line!!**
          IntValue = Regex.Match(node.Children.ElementAt(i).DisplayName.Value, @"\d+").Value;
     }
}
```

*NOTE: `DisplayName.Value` is a `string`

Comment: I removed my comment: Regex.Match returns type `Match` which wont cast to `int` (obviously). I'm adding a different answer

Comment: @Brandon Yep just saw that too, thought it returned `string` too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get from string to int, use int.Parse(string), it returns the int represented by the passed string and throws if the input format is incorrect.

```
int.Parse(node.Children.ElementAt(i).DisplayName.Value)
```

You can also use int.TryParse if you don't want the throw. in that case you would use:

```
int parsedValue;
if (int.TryParse(node.Children.ElementAt(i).DisplayName.Value, out parsedValue))
{
  ///Do whatever with the int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is becuase you're casting from `Match` to `int` in this call

`IntValue = Regex.Match(node.Children.ElementAt(i).DisplayName.Value, @"\d+").Value;`

Try something like this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(node.Children.ElementAt(i).DisplayName.Value, @"\d+").Value;
int value = m.Matches[0] //You'll have to verify this line, I'm going from memory here.
```

Comment: Didn't the OP say that DisplayName.Value was a string?

Comment: I saw his comment in code as this "//The children of this node have DisplayNames that are integers"

Comment: If the display names ARE indeed strings, my above solution will still work, he'll just need to remove the `ToString()` call as it will be redundant. Edit: Yes he did. Updated my answer.