# Adding a child node in the middle of a list of other children

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, nodes, children

This question is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310745/having-trouble-converting-string-to-int). Basically what I want to do is add nodes to my `treeView` in numerical order. Right now I am working with a list of child nodes. Each child has a `DisplayName` of a numerical value. In my program I have a loop that checks if the node being added has a `DisplayName` that is less than the `DisplayName` of the current child in the loop. If the new child's `DisplayName` is less than the child being checked I would like to add the new node before the already existing one. I am having trouble figuring out a method to do this.

Here is my code:

```
var node = Data.GetAllChildren(x => x.Children).Distinct().ToList().First(x => x.identify == 'B');

//Get # of children -- if children exist
if (node.Children.Count() > 0)
{
    newChildTitle = int.Parse(nodeName.Value); //node to add

    for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count(); i++)
    {
        currentChildTitle = int.Parse(node.Children.ElementAt(i).DisplayName.Value); //current node value

        if (newChildTitle == currentChildTitle) //Check if location already exists
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, that location name already exists under this category.", "Duplicate Location Name", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            break;
        }
        else if (newChildTitle < currentChildTitle) //If new location value is less, add before current location in Tree
        {
            //CODE WOULD GO HERE**        
            break;
        }
    }
}
else //if no children exist, just add
    node.Children.Add(CreateBlockingLocation(model, blockTreeCollection, nodeName));
```

XAML of the `TreeView` (the `TreeView` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`):

```
<!-- Tree view items & Functions -->
    <TreeView Name="Tree_One" IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.DataTreeEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTree.Data}" />
```

Data and Properties of the `ObservableCollection<HierarchicalVM>` that the `TreeView` is bound to:

```
private HierarchicalVM _parent;
private ObservableCollection<HierarchicalVM> _children;

public HierarchicalVM()
{
    Commands = new ObservableCollection<Command>();
}

//Relationship Properties
public HierarchicalVM Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
    set
    {
        _parent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => Parent);
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<HierarchicalVM> Children
{
   get { return _children ?? (_children = new ObservableCollection<HierarchicalVM>()); }
   set { _children = value; }
}
```

**Current Solution attempt:**

```
//Gets parent item (Data is the complete Tree)
var node = Data.GetAllChildren(x => x.Children).Distinct().ToList().First(x => x.identify == 'B'); 

if (!node.Children.Any(n => n.numValue == newNumValue))
{
    //Error is on this line: **Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'
    node.Children = node.Children.Add(newNode).Orderby(n => n.numValue);
}
```

Comment: Since this is WPF, why isn't your treeview bound to a collection, in which case you could use the InsertAt function of the collection? Manually messing the with children list is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Hold on, it is bound to a collection, maybe I'm just taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Yeah, it should be bound to an ObservableCollection, and you want to modify that, not the visual element's children.

Comment: So `node.Children.Add()` is not the correct way to add a child node? What would be the correct way to add children then?

Comment: Your XAML should be bound in such a way that you just change the underlying collection and it propagates up. Can you post your XAML and any associated ViewModel code?

Comment: I posted the `TreeView`'s XAML. I guess I would just need to know the correct operations to use on the collection.

Comment: Please let me know what else you would like to see if anything.

Comment: Do you have a hierarchical data template or data code I could see? You want the InsertAt function, but my example won't be very good without knowing what the data looks like.

Comment: I do, the `ObservableCollection` is of a ViewModel type. I will post what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps! It should at least get you close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming you already have a reference to the Parent object (not the DataTreeItem UI Element), there are two ways I can think of to accomplish this. This is off the top of my head with a little bit of checking against MSDN, so I apologize for any bugs.

```
Parent parent = //however you are getting the parent
if (!parent.Children.Any(n => n.DisplayName == newNode.DisplayName))
{
   parent.Children.Add(newNode)
   parent.Children = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(parent.Children.OrderBy(n => n.DisplayName));
   //OR,
   parent.Children.InsertItem(parent.Children.IndexOf(parent.Children.OrderBy(n => n.DisplayName).Last(n => n.DisplayName < newNode.DisplayName)), newNode);
}
```

The first method just adds the new item and resorts the list, which gets you the same result as an in-place insert. The second actually does a in-place insert, but is more complicated because you have to find the index to insert at.

If the list is already sorted you could remove the OrderBy in the second method. This also assumes that DisplayName is an int and a property of each child node (which from the code you posted it isn't, but it should be).

Clearly I don't understand your architecture, so I will explain how I think it should be, and then perhaps you can discover where your code is broken.

We have a object type called Parent, which contains a collection called children, like so:

```
class Parent<T>
{
   ObservableCollection<T> Children;
}
```

Now we have an collection of Parent called Data in the view model that the TreeView is bound to. Somehow, we are getting a single instance of this Parent class (which definitely shouldn't be void, the fact that your "node.Children" object is should be a HUGE red flag).

If you agree with what I said above, the insert code I posted should work.

Please let me know if I can clarify or add to this answer, or help in any other way.

Comment: Okay, I'm attempting to use this solution but I have to use `node.Children` in all of the areas that you have `Children`. When using this, I get the error: `Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'`. (I am using the first option)

Comment: @Ericafterdark, I apologize for not being clear. You need a reference to the parent, and you want to use that objects Children property. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have the parent referenced and I believe that I am using it in the exact same manner. Please take a look at my question update, I've added my current solution attempt.

Comment: In the code you posted, what is Data? It sounds like you are still searching the visual tree. All of this is just in the bound collections.

Comment: Data is the complete `TreeView`, node is the part that I am working with. Data is declared like this: `public ObservableCollection<Type> Data { get; set; }`

Comment: Updated to try and get past this, let me know what you think

Comment: So if `node.Children` is void, would it be correct to ask you how to change it so that it is not void?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49683/discussion-between-lordtakkera-and-eric-after-dark)